# Check if element of vector is in corresponding element of list

Tags: r

I have two vectors, `a` and `b`, which is `a <- c(1,3)`, another `b <- list(c(1,4),c(2,5))`.

is there any elegant way to find if the element in `a` is in the corresponding row in `b`?

for example, `a[1]` is in `b[1]`, `a[2]` is not in `b[2]`, so I should get a vector value of `c(TRUE, FALSE)`.

I tried `a %in% b`, which is wrong.

Comment: or `mapply("%in%", a, b)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `sapply` to loop through the indices `idx`, checking if `a[idx]` is in `b[[idx]]`:

```
sapply(seq_along(a), function(idx) a[idx] %in% b[[idx]])
# [1]  TRUE FALSE
```